# Output custom text attribute in catalog list.phtml (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, attributes

I made a attribute set and custom text field attribute. Now I need the value of the attribute shown in list.phtml (catalog).

I tried without success:

Fail 1

```
<?php  echo $product->getAttributeText('catalog_description'); ?>
```

Fail 2

```
<?php echo $product->getAttributeText('catalog_description'); ?>
```

Fail 3

```
<?php $product->getAttributeText('catalog_description'); ?>
```

Fail 4

```
<?php echo $catalog_description; ?>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm having the exact same problem. What I'm surprised by is that some attributes are available using the getdata() method, for example price, sku and weight, although these are also attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution, this works:**

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getcatalog_description(), 'catalog_description'); ?>
```

In the Attribute setting in Magento 2 choose in Storefront properties **YES** for:

- Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront
- Used in Product Listing